How to do bulk upload in particular key value for json field in django
I need to update a particular key value in json field and other field should not be impacted or override.
variant_to_update = master_models.Variant.objects.filter( trust_markers__contains = {trust_marker_type: True})
model_to_update = master_models.Model.objects.filter( trust_markers__contains = {trust_marker_type: True})

for variant in variant_to_update:
    variant.trust_markers[trust_marker_type] = False
    variant.save(update_fields = ['trust_markers'])

for model in model_to_update:
    model.trust_markers[trust_marker_type] = False
    model.save(update_fields = ['trust_markers'])

I find this solution of appending it to a list and then do bulk upload
master_models.Variant.objects.bulk_update(variant_updates, ['trust_markers'])

What database do you use?

@willeM_VanOnsem postgresql

@willeM_VanOnsem any idea or this approach is fine? we cannot optimize further.
